# RAM slot free or not

Tags: ram

This question might not be so relevant here, but I want to know if there is some command tool that gives me the currently available RAM slots in my machine, also if any of them is free, and information of the reserved slots. Since I want to extend the RAM of my system, I need to know if there is a free RAM slot in my computer. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo hwinfo --bios 2> /dev/null | grep 'Memory Device: #' -A14 | grep 'Size'`
this tells me about my ram sticks

```
~$ sudo hwinfo --bios 2> /dev/null | grep 'Memory Device: #' -A14 | grep 'Size'
    Size: 4 GB
    Size: No Memory Installed
    Size: 4 GB
    Size: 4 GB
```

It is always better to look on the motherboard and read the manual about memory limitations as some system BIOSes say they have more slots than they actually do

Comment: I get the following output for this:     
Size: 1 GB  
Size: 1 GB
    does this mean my computer doesn't have free slots? It can't be extended anymore, right?

Comment: @shivshnkr That's a question to ask the manual for the motherboard in your computer, or the manual for your computer itself (depending on what type it is). You can possibly install 2GB or 4GB modules in those slots, depending on what the maximum your computer's hardware will accept, and just remove the 1GB modules.

Comment: Clearly your system only has 2 slots and has 1gb per slot, consult your manual to find out if it support larger capacity ram sticks

Comment: but are there chances it has any hidden slots, that are not displayed using commands? Also while doing memory test during boot time saw some output similar to this, some description regarding both slots containing 1 GB RAM sticks.

Comment: I doubt it would miss any, 2 slots is typical of a mainstream oem system, my laptop only has 1 slot and a integrated 2gb chip, you still need to check your manual `sudo hwinfo --bios 2>/dev/null | grep 'Product:'` should get your model to so you can look it up